# Mock method globally with unittest.mock.patch

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, patch

I'm trying to mock a method that is called by another method in a separate module. Specifically, I would like the call to `foo` in bar.py to be replaced with a call to `mock_foo`:

foo.py

```
def foo():
    return 'foo'
```

bar.py

```
from foo import foo

def bar.py():
    return foo()
```

test.py

```
from bar import bar

def mock_foo():
    return 'mock_foo'

def testmethod():
    with patch('foo.foo', mock_foo):
        print(bar())  
        # Expected output:'mock_foo'
```

The `patch` approach above doesn't work. Is this possible to do with the mock library? If so, how should I modify test.py?

Comment: You need to patch `'bar.foo'` - that's the symbol referring to the `foo` method that you need to replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should patch the `foo` function imported inside `bar` module. So, the target should be `bar.foo`.

E.g.

`foo.py`:

```py
def foo():
    return 'foo'
```

`bar.py`:

```py
from foo import foo


def bar():
    return foo()
```

`test_bar.py`:

```py
from bar import bar
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch


def mock_foo():
    return 'mock_foo'


class BarTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bar(self):
        with patch('bar.foo', mock_foo):
            print(bar())
            self.assertEqual(bar(), 'mock_foo')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test result:

```
⚡  coverage run /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab/src/stackoverflow/66540831/test_bar.py && coverage report -m --include './src/**'
mock_foo
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
Name                                     Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
----------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/66540831/bar.py            3      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/66540831/foo.py            2      1    50%   2
src/stackoverflow/66540831/test_bar.py      12      0   100%
----------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                       17      1    94%
```